# Outlook OAUTH 2.0 access_token unable to login in office 365 account

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, office365, access-token, azure-ad-msal

we are using OAUTH 2.0 and msal4j library to achieve access_token, and have finally received the access_token but by using that access_token we are unable to login in office 365 account.

we are beginner for this OAUTH , kindly let us know where we are wrong.

please find below code we used:

```
          try {
            TokenCacheAspect tokenCacheAspect = new TokenCacheAspect("sample_cache.json");

            PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(clientId)
                    .authority(AUTHORITY)
                    .setTokenCacheAccessAspect(tokenCacheAspect)
                    .build();

            Set<IAccount> accountsInCache = pca.getAccounts().join();
            // Take first account in the cache. In a production application, you would filter
            // accountsInCache to get the right account for the user authenticating.
            IAccount account1 = accountsInCache.iterator().next();
          scopes.add("openid");
          scopes.add("profile");
          scopes.add("User.Read");
          scopes.add("offline_access");
          scopes.add("Mail.Read");

            try {
                SilentParameters silentParameters =
                        SilentParameters
                                .builder( scopes, account1)
                                .build();

                // try to acquire token silently. This call will fail since the token cache
                // does not have any data for the user you are trying to acquire a token for
                result = pca.acquireTokenSilently(silentParameters).join();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                if (ex.getCause() instanceof MsalException) {

                    InteractiveRequestParameters parameters = InteractiveRequestParameters
                            .builder(new URI("http://localhost"))
                            .scopes(scopes)
                            .build();

                    // Try to acquire a token interactively with system browser. If successful, you should see
                    // the token and account information printed out to console
                    result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).join();

                } else {
                    // Handle other exceptions accordingly
                    throw ex;
                }

            }


   

            URL url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + result.accessToken());
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            String response = HttpClientHelper.getResponseStringFromConn(conn);

            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new IOException(response);
            }

            JSONObject responseObject = HttpClientHelper.processResponse(responseCode, response);
        }catch (Exception e){
            PrintUtil.printEmailLogFile("exception while acquiring token for outlook");
        }
```

Note: we successfully received the access_token, but by using this token we are unable to connect to store(imap) . getting authentication failure

Comment: Does the token contain the required claims?  If the token is a JWT try pasting the token into jwt.io this will decode the token and show you its contains so you can inspect the claims.

Comment: Perhaps these links will be helpful:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#microsoft-graph-permission-names.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials